# DOMException failed to execute 'setPointerCapture' on 'Element' and 'releasePointerCapture'

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have created a hybrid app in which I used bxslider and placed div inside it as follow,

```
<div class="bxslider">
            <div id="chart1" style="text-align:center">
                <span id="barChartTitle">Bar Chart</span>
                <svg id="chartCanvas" class="margintop40"></svg>
            </div>
            <div id="chart2" style="text-align:center">
                <span id="trendChartTitle">Trend Chart</span> 
                <svg id="chartCanvas" class="margintop40"></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when ever I make a touch over the bxslider in the html view I receive the following error,

```
   jquery.bxslider.js:1109 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setPointerCapture' on 'Element': InvalidPointerId
    at HTMLDivElement.onTouchStart (http://localhost:8100/js/jquery.bxslider.js:1109:34)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (http://localhost:8100/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (http://localhost:8100/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
onTouchStart @ jquery.bxslider.js:1109
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
jquery.bxslider.js:1234 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'releasePointerCapture' on 'Element': InvalidPointerId
    at HTMLDivElement.onTouchEnd (http://localhost:8100/js/jquery.bxslider.js:1234:32)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (http://localhost:8100/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (http://localhost:8100/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find out why the error occurs, please help.

Comment: I have the same issue. My Bxslider galleries were working fine till I tested the other day and started giving me this error. Interestingly the error occurs only on Android devices and not on the emulator.

Comment: I'm developing a hybrid app , so while testing the app in chrom browser using simulator I found this errors in console, this error occur if  I make any click on the Bxslider.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm stuck as no other slides integrates as neatly as bxslider.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a workaround that works. Use this snippet of code:

```
var chromePointerEvents = typeof PointerEvent === 'function'; if (chromePointerEvents) { if (orig.pointerId === undefined) { return; } }
```

Insert after:

```
touchPoints = (typeof orig.changedTouches !== 'undefined') ? orig.changedTouches : [orig];
```

of file jquery.bxslider.js

More info here  [read simplicitytrade answer on Github](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/1086#issuecomment-276687028).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniela, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @BobSwager search in jquery.bxslider.js for touchPoints = (typeof orig.changedTouches !== 'undefined') ? orig.changedTouches : [orig]; and insert it after that

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try this current version?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Good to know there is a new version out. Have you tested it on Android? Has the issue been resolved?